# SQL: Count value une a field

Tags: mysql, sql, count, field

I would like to know if it is possible to have this kind of schema:

Table 1:

```
Field1 | Field4 | Field3
Field1 | Field4 | Field3 
Field1 | Field4 | Field3
```

Table 2:

```
Field4 | Field5(Number of Field3)
```

To explain the schema, my tables have a similar field, (number4)

And my real question is:

Can I have a dynamic database where the field5 would be the count of field 3 where Table1.field4 = Table2.field4,  or should I change it by hand with PHP?

Edit: "Can you provide some example data for this schema? (And perhaps some more meaningful names.)"

Table: prod
             Product | Description | nbOfreview 
             Product | Description | nbOfreview

Table: Reviews
             Review | Description | Product

Comment: field5 is a derived attribute, is not good practice store attribute that you can derive on the fly.

Comment: Can you provide some example data for this schema? (And perhaps some more meaningful names.)

Comment: You can do that with a mysql view

Comment: You might want to ask "your real question" first, and add details afterward. My first instinct was to vote to close this as "not a real question".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an extra table.
You can use a view.

e.g:

```
CREATE VIEW v_data AS
SELECT field4, COUNT(field3) F_COUNT
  FROM <YOUR-TABLE>
GROUP BY  field4
```